# How to read a datamatrix code locally in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, datamatrix

I'am working on an Ionic 3 based mobile application, it needs to be able to work offline. One of its features is to read [data matrix two-dimensional codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix) while being offline.

I have tried using Ionic Native plugins such as Barcode Scanner or QR Scanner with no luck (since they do not support data matrix). I have also been looking for third party options such as Manatee, RT Scan ad dbrjs but they are cloud based services, which won't be available offline.

Am I missing an alternative? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic native barcode scanner does support Data Matrix as specified in [docs here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner#using-the-plugin)